# Libgdx IOS Not Working?

Tags: ios, eclipse, xcode, libgdx, robovm

I recently finished making a libgdx app for android, and I am currently trying to port it to ios. I have eclipse kepler installed, with the robovm plugin on top of it. My mac is also running osx mavericks. Now for the actual problem- Whenever i try to run my application as an iOS project, it comes up with an error. Here's what comes up in the console-

```
3/28/14 8:54:34 PM: [ERROR] ld: framework not found UIKit
3/28/14 8:54:34 PM: [ERROR] clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
3/28/14 8:54:35 PM: [ERROR] Build failed
```

And this is what I get in the details of the error-

```
Build failed. Check the RoboVM console for more information.
```

Command:

```
clang++ -o "/Users/akudva/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/build/BulletTest-robovm/RobovmLauncher (2)/macosx/x86/com.ashwin.BulletTest.RobovmLauncher/BulletTest" -g -arch i386 "-Wl,-filelist,/Users/akudva/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/build/BulletTest-robovm/RobovmLauncher (2)/macosx/x86/com.ashwin.BulletTest.RobovmLauncher/objects" -L /Users/akudva/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/robovm-0.0.10/lib/vm/macosx/x86 -ObjC -exported_symbols_list "/Users/akudva/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/build/BulletTest-robovm/RobovmLauncher (2)/macosx/x86/com.ashwin.BulletTest.RobovmLauncher/exported_symbols" -Wl,-no_implicit_dylibs -Wl,-dead_strip -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -lrobovm-bc -force_load /Users/akudva/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.robovm.eclipse.ui/robovm-0.0.10/lib/vm/macosx/x86/librobovm-rt.a -lrobovm-debug -lrobovm-core -lgc -lpthread -ldl -lm -liconv -lsqlite3 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenAL -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -force_load "/Users/akudva/Desktop/Eclipse Libgdx Mac Projects/BulletTestProject/BulletTest-robovm/libs/ios/libgdx.a" -force_load "/Users/akudva/Desktop/Eclipse Libgdx Mac Projects/BulletTestProject/BulletTest-robovm/libs/ios/libObjectAL.a" failed (Exit value: 1)
```

Any ideas? I could really use some help here, since I even tried to run it with the default libgdx app, and it still didn't work.

Comment: Do you have the latest non-beta xcode installed? What does `xcode-select --print-path` say?

Comment: Yes, I have Xcode 5.1 installed, but as I am doing this completely from eclipse, I'm not even using it. Eclipse allows you to compile the project without going to Xcode with the robo-vm plugin installed. The problem is when I compile it, it comes up with the error shown above.  @Chase

Comment: Please show us your robovm.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

I not familiar with RoboVM, but looking at their [docs](http://docs.robovm.com/user/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/) they say

Prerequisites:

In order to use RoboVM the following is required:

- A Mac running Mac OS X 10.9 or later
- Oracle’s Java SE JDK 7 or later
- Xcode 6.x from the Mac App Store

I guess it cannot work, because you have Xcode 5